# Asynchronous application execution in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous

I want to execute a file through Qt. QProcess is working like a charm, however, it blocks my application and waits for the one I just opened to exit, and I need it[my main application] to exit as soon as the other application is opened. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [QProcess::startDetached](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#startDetached) ?

Comment: Seems like I missed it when I went over QProcess. Thanks!